# What does "the world was treated to the spectacle of Joe Biden insulting his Russian counterpart" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, semantics

What does this mean:

> the world was treated to the spectacle of Joe Biden insulting his Russian counterpart

I can't think of something desirable or enjoyable as to make sense of this phrase, is the author saying the world was to enjoy this insults?

Comment: What do you not understand? The literal meaning? The nuance? A certain expression? The vocabulary?

Comment: I do not understand the expression "to be treated to the spectacle" as I do not believe the world will enjoy or was looking forward to a president insulting another president. As the utterance to treat someone to something means to delight people.

Answer (score 3):

Although we normally use 'treat' to mean 'provide a pleasant experience', we can use the term ironically, as in the quoted sentence. We can say ironically that one or more people were 'treated' to the spectacle of something bad or undesirable if we wish to emphasise our disapproval, amusement, etc. We can add further disapproving ironic emphasis by saying or writing 'the edifying spectacle'.

irony is the expression of one's meaning by using language that normally signifies the opposite, typically for humorous or emphatic effect.

*Due to sudden collapse of a toilet wall, the visitors to the palace were treated to the spectacle of a royal person wiping their posterior.*

*for the next several weeks all who encountered him, from Governor General to hack reporter, were treated to the spectacle of the Prime Minister of Canada reeling drunk.*

*Sentencing him at Newcastle Crown Court, Judge Penny Moreland said: "The people who lived there were treated to the spectacle of you and Steven Caulkin brawling in broad daylight".*

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion is that any spectacle (public show) is enjoyable and entertaining, by virtue of being novel, interesting, and exciting.

So it's not so much the insults themselves that the world enjoys, but rather the unusual and striking event of one major world leader directly insulting another. In international relations, that's quite exciting compared to the tact and diplomacy usually displayed.